# Can I stop Windows from over-eagerly reclaiming physical memory?

Tags: windows, memory

I am writing a server app which I want to efficiently use ALL available physical RAM of the machine when possible. The plan is that it will allocate physical pages using AWE until it detects that 99% of physical memory and stop when 1% is free, and any time physical memory drops below 1% free, it will free physical pages it doesn't need.

However when I put this plan into practice, Windows seems to think any time it has 99% of RAM in use it would be a good idea to free up more physical memory, and so it starts paging all sorts of stuff to disk, and my system crashes.

How can I tell Windows it is OK to have 99% of RAM in use and it doesn't need to try to page stuff back to disk until it reaches whatever its default perceived ideal level of usage is (I guess it will be something like 90%...)

Note: Raymond says 'Unless you are designing a system where you are the only program running on the computer, this is a bad idea.'

In this server scenario this *is* basically intended to be the only app running on the computer. But unfortunately there are some OS/background tasks that need to run...

But certainly I don't expect there is any *other* process on the computer indulging in this 'use all but 1% of RAM' behavior...?

Update: I've done more experimentation and started to wonder if I'm somewhat asking the wrong question. My assumption that windows is being overeager may be wrong. Perhaps the question should instead have been 'how can I determine how much physical RAM my process can safely use without compromising overall responsiveness on the machine'?

Comment: Yeah, that 1% probably isn't enough.  Why not stop at 10% and see if that helps.  Also, what's that terrible smell?

Comment: If you consume 99% of all memory there's only 1% left for everything else. That leads to paging out. Isn't that expected in this situation?

Comment: @usr my experience has been that Windows (and Linux too) will throw out code pages to reuse the memory for disk cache. That leads to some unfortunate performance characteristics, and if your swap disk is full you can definitely crash. "over-eagerly" is a good way to put it.

Comment: @MarkRansom What you say is true but how is this related to what I said?  Windows has not choice but to swap out when almost all of RAM is being consumed by the OPs program. What else could it possibly do?

Comment: @usr it does have a choice - disk caching is totally optional. A certain amount is necessary for adequate performance, but to treat it on an equal footing with program space is absurd. If you're doing a sequential read on a 16GB file, kiss your RAM goodbye.

Comment: See also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/01/18/10257834.aspx

Comment: As a footnote to that, I would add that if you *really* need exclusive access to 99% of physical RAM, you should probably consider using a lower-level or customized operating system rather than one designed for general-purpose use.

Comment: @MarkRansom this is not about disk caching. If 15.999GB of 16GB are consumed by program A (and all of it is in memory) then all other programs must be paged out. Simple as that. Again I don't see what point you are actually making.

Comment: Rephrased the question since people seem unclear as to why what I'm asking makes sense.

Comment: @Harry thanks for the link - that is the best answer I got out of this so far!

Comment: @usr: I think what Mark means is that Windows tends to page out the application's memory prematurely, e.g., the application has 15.9GB of committed virtual memory, but only, say, 12GB of that is actually being kept in memory, because Windows has decided to use 0.5GB for other applications and 3.5GB for the disk cache.  He appears to be arguing that you would get better overall performance if Windows always prioritized application memory over the disk cache.  (I'm not sure I agree.)  With the latest edit to the question, we can see this isn't the OPs issue.

Comment: OK, I hadn't realized that your process really was allocating non-swappable memory.  To clarify, does your algorithm simply allocate 99% of total physical memory, or do you keep allocating until free physical memory drops below 1%?  If the latter, how do you measure free physical memory?  The fact that the system is crashing suggests that you're doing it wrong. :-)  One more question: at the point where the system crashes, how much memory has your program allocated?

Comment: Also, how much RAM does the server have anyway?

Comment: @Harry Assume it has > 20 GB. I've measured free physical memory mainly using GlobalMemoryStatusEx.

Comment: I'm not sure how those figures help you if you're really aiming at a particular total memory usage - `dwMemoryLoad` is the only one that looks relevant, and since it only measures in 1% intervals I don't see how you would use it to keep usage at 99%.  On the other hand, if you're just using `ullTotalPhys` that should work, except that you need to leave enough memory for Windows to function - I believe 4GB is the recommended figure, though you might get away with 2GB.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The Windows memory manager runs at a lower level than your program and knows nothing about your program (and even if it did, it has no reason to assume your program is the good citizen you claim it to be. What if your program crashes, or has an off-by-one error in a loop that `malloc`s? What about other programs that need memory while yours is running? What about the thousand other scenarios that the guys who wrote the Windows MM encountered when they were writing it?)

Don't try to be cleverer than Windows. A more productive use of your time would be to consider if your application *really needs* to allocate 99% physical memory up front.

Comment: Just so.  For completeness, however, note that you *can* make memory non-swappable, though doing so for 99% of RAM would be suicidal.

Comment: All true but I don't see how this helps the OP. Doing nothing is not an option for him to resolve the problem. And probably he really wants to allocate as much as possible.

Comment: note: I wouldn't care if Windows tries to reclaim physical memory when available RAM drops below the last 1% (when my program has a bug, or a new app starts, or whatever). I just wonder why it is doing all this paging *before* then - it seems like nobody actually needs it to reclaim that memory?

Comment: Look at it this way: on a 24GB machine, using up 99% of physical memory leaves Windows with roughly 246MB.  Now imagine trying to run a modern version of Windows on a machine that only has 246MB of RAM. :-)

Comment: @Harry I'm not saying the server process uses 99% of physical memory. I'm saying it always leaves 1% of physical memory free for anybody to play with, at all times. However suddenly it occurs to me a slightly different reason of why this is going to be a problem...

Comment: @TimLovell-Smith: but you say you're using GlobalMemoryStatusEx, which as far as I can see doesn't give you the information you would need in order to do that.  You're not mistaking the value of `ullAvailPhys` for the amount of free memory by any chance?

Comment: @Harry isn't that what the documentation says it is?

Comment: The documentation says "the amount of physical memory that can be immediately reused without having to write its contents to disk first".  I'm not absolutely certain, but presumably that includes all pages that are read-only, e.g., most application code and constant data, and possibly also pages that are read/write but haven't yet been written to.  There's also the zero list (pages that have already been zeroed and so are ready to be assigned) though I'm not sure how big that has to be to maintain adequate performance - possibly it isn't relevant on this scale.